# Keep getting error copying sheet into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Copy function error. Wanting to copy the sheet over to a created sheet with the date indicated. What is going on?

```
    Dim Dateini As String
    Dateini = "2021-03-31"
    Sheets("Sheet3").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = Dateini
```

Comment: ` Sheets("Sheet3").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = Dateini` needs to be `set ws= Sheets("Sheet3").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count)`   `ws.Name = Dateini` i think

Comment: i'm trying to create a copy of the sheet and naming that copy to Dateini

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: It doesn't work, even if you put the `After...` in parentheses. Also, you have to be more careful when you use `Sheets` or `Worksheets`.

Comment: Yes understood, not my code, just showing using their existing code.  I'd have put an answer if doing full solution.   https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/copy-a-worksheet-an-rename-using-vba.494503/ this was the 1st google return

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: You have used the wrong code of the person asking the question instead of the answer below (containing `ActiveSheet`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy a Sheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Const Dateini As String = "2021-03-31"
    ' Use 'ThisWorkbook' if it is the workbook containing this code.
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Sheets("Sheet3").Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .ActiveSheet.Name = Dateini
    End With
End Sub
```